# Method 'WriteLine' of object 'ITextStream' failed

Tags: vb6

This may be a basic question, but was unable to figure out the issue as am quite new to VB 6.
This is what I came through on searching online for this error code

> “Method'~' of object '~' failed" this usually happens when dll are not
>   registered. Precisely, when the runtime  is not even able to tell what
>   the object is, and the object is not able to propagate more infos
>   back. It could be any component. It is a mismatched DLL file.”

Tried registering the *scrrun.dll* using regsvr32.exe too, yet no luck

Getting the error in the below code block, while trying to run the program

```
Sub PrintToConsole(ByVal LineToPrint As String)
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    fso.GetStandardStream(StdOut).WriteLine (LineToPrint)
End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look at this page. There's more to it than just using GetStandardStream. http://www.nirsoft.net/vb/console_application_visual_basic.html

Comment: Most VB6 programs are compiled and linked for the Windows Subsystem, where there are no standard I/O streams to work with.  Most likely that's where things went wrong.

Comment: @Bob77 hope you mean to say about running the **LINK.exe**
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98\LINK.EXE" /EDIT /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE Application.exe`

Comment: I'm fully aware of that and the fact that you can manually do that, or even specify the Subsystem within the .VBP file for that matter.  Most casual users of VB6 are unaware of either though.

Comment: @Bob77 awesome actually the **Windows Subsystem** was the issue, had a couple of _LINK.exe_ in my system had to run the right one to fix it.More information can be found [here](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/10/14/how-to-create-a-vb6-console-program/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To link for the Console  subsystem you can add these lines to the end of your .VBP file:

```
[VBCompiler]
LinkSwitches=/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE
```

Then the compiled EXE should work fine.

Also consider this example program.  Here is Module1.bas:

```
Option Explicit

Private StdIn As Scripting.TextStream
Private StdOut As Scripting.TextStream

'--- Only required for testing in IDE or Windows Subsystem ===
Private Declare Function AllocConsole Lib "kernel32" () As Long
Private Declare Function GetConsoleTitle Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "GetConsoleTitleA" ( _
    ByVal lpConsoleTitle As String, _
    ByVal nSize As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function FreeConsole Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Private mEnableConsole As Boolean
Private mAllocated As Boolean

Private Property Get EnableConsole() As Boolean
    EnableConsole = mEnableConsole
End Property

Private Property Let EnableConsole(ByVal RHS As Boolean)
    Dim Title As String

    If Not RHS And mEnableConsole Then
        If mAllocated Then
            StdOut.Write "Press enter to continue..."
            StdIn.ReadLine
            FreeConsole
            mAllocated = False
        End If
        mEnableConsole = False
    ElseIf RHS And Not mEnableConsole Then
        Title = Space$(260)
        If GetConsoleTitle(Title, 260) = 0 Then
            AllocConsole
            mAllocated = True
        End If
        mEnableConsole = True
    End If
End Property
'--- End testing ---------------------------------------------

Private Sub Main()
    Dim Msg As String

    EnableConsole = True
    On Error GoTo Cleanup

    With New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        Set StdIn = .GetStandardStream(Scripting.StdIn)
        Set StdOut = .GetStandardStream(Scripting.StdOut)
    End With

    With StdOut
        .Write "Hello from "
        .Write App.Path
        .Write "\"
        .Write App.EXEName
        .WriteLine ".exe"

        .Write "Command line: ["
        .Write Command$()
        .WriteLine "]"

        .WriteLine "Type an input message and press Enter:"

        Msg = StdIn.ReadLine()
        .WriteLine "I saw:"
        .WriteLine Msg
    End With
    Msg = 1 / 0 'Cause an exception for illustration!

Cleanup:
    If Err Then
        With StdOut
            .Write "#Error: "
            .Write CStr(Err.Number)
            .Write ", "
            .WriteLine Err.Description
        End With
    End If
    EnableConsole = False
End Sub
```

This can be handy because most of us enjoy being able to test and debug.

For testing the compiled program, you might try something like TestProject1.cmd:

```
@Echo Off
Project1 Run from CMD file!
Pause
```

That assumes you compiled as Project1.exe of course.

You can make `StdIn`, `StdOut`, and `EnableConsole` all `Public` for access from other modules too.  I'd probably make just the `EnableConsole` "getter" `Public` myself though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim fso as Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.GetStandardStream(StdOut).WriteLine (LineToPrint)
```

Comment: Still the same issue, debug shows error in line `fso.GetStandardStream(StdOut).WriteLine (LineToPrint)`

Answer (score 0):

The GetStandardStream Method return a TextStream object.

FileSystemObject Object
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50(v=vs.84).aspx

GetStandardStream Method
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6hbz9es(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: The issue seems to be there only when the GetStandardStream method is used, also tried to comment the below two lines to debug
`Dim fso As New FileSystemObject`
`fso.GetStandardStream(StdOut).WriteLine (LineToPrint)`

Followed by 
`Debug.Print "This is the Error" & (LineToPrint)`

The _Method 'WriteLine' of object 'ITextStream' failed_ error didn't pop up